# Insert elements into numpy array so that the minimum spacing is arbitrary

Tags: python, numpy

Given an ordered `numpy` array of floats (min to max), I need to ensure that the spacing between elements is smaller than an arbitrary float I call `step`.

This is my code and as far as I can see it works, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this:

```
import numpy as np

def slpitArr(arr, step=3.):
    """
    Insert extra elements into array so that the maximum spacing between
    elements is 'step'.
    """
    # Keep going until no more elements need to be added
    while True:
        flagExit = True
        for i, v in enumerate(arr):
            # Catch last element in list
            try:
                if abs(arr[i + 1] - v) > step:
                    new_v = (arr[i + 1] + v) / 2.
                    flagExit = False
                    break
            except IndexError:
                pass
        if flagExit:
            break
        # Insert new element
        arr = np.insert(arr, i + 1, new_v)

    return arr


aa = np.array([10.08, 14.23, 19.47, 21.855, 24.34, 25.02])

print(aa)
print(slpitArr(aa))
```

which results in:

```
[10.08  14.23  19.47  21.855 24.34  25.02 ]
[10.08  12.155 14.23  16.85  19.47  21.855 24.34  25.02 ]
```

Comment: _"...I need to ensure that the spacing between elements is smaller than..."_ What do you mean by "spacing"? Is it the delta between adjacent _values_? Or is it difference between indices (position) in the vector?

Comment: It's the delta between adjacent values. I currently insert the middle point if the delta is larger than `step`.

Comment: I managed to think of an alternative solution: `bb = [[aa[i]] if aa[i+1]-aa[i] < 3 else [aa[i], (aa[i]+ aa[i+1])/2]  for i in range(len(aa)-1)]` and then `bb = [j for i in bb for j in i] +[aa[-1]]`. If you approve, I can post it as an answer

Comment: This will only do one pass over the array. I would need to run this multiple times. That's why the `while` is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one-pass solution that

1) calculates the differences *d* between consecutive points

2) ceil-divides *d* by step to get *m*

2a) optionally rounds *m* up to the nearest power of two

3) divides *d* by *m* and repeats the result *m* times

4) forms the cumulative sum

Here is the code. Technical note: The first element of d is not a difference but the "anchor", so it equals the first element of data.

```
def fill(data, step, force_power_of_two=True):
    d = data.copy()
    d[1:] -= data[:-1]
    if force_power_of_two:
        m = 1 << (np.frexp(np.nextafter(d / step, -1))[1]).clip(0, None)
    else:
        m = -(d // -step).astype(int)
    m[0] = 1
    d /= m
    return np.cumsum(d.repeat(m))
```

Sample run:

```
>>> inp
array([10.08 , 14.23 , 19.47 , 21.855, 24.34 , 25.02 ])
>>> fill(inp, 3)
array([10.08 , 12.155, 14.23 , 16.85 , 19.47 , 21.855, 24.34 , 25.02 ])
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your result. I get back `[10.08       10.91       11.74       12.57       13.4        14.23
 14.97857143 15.72714286 16.47571429 17.22428571 17.97285714 18.72142857
 19.47       19.768125   20.06625    20.364375   20.6625     20.960625
 21.25875    21.556875   21.855      22.13111111 22.40722222 22.68333333
 22.95944444 23.23555556 23.51166667 23.78777778 24.06388889 24.34
 24.41555556 24.49111111 24.56666667 24.64222222 24.71777778 24.79333333
 24.86888889 24.94444444 25.02      ]
`

Comment: @Gabriel of course you can't. Because I'm too stupid to copy'n'paste. In the third line (assignment to `m`) it must be `d`, not `data`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I can reproduce the result now but it only seems to work if `step=3`. If I use `step=2.5`  the results are different from my code.

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, the logic is different: Your midpoint algorithm will always cut a given gap into a power of two gaps. Mine uses the smallest number necessary. If you absolutely want your behavior I can modify my algorithm, all one needs to do is round m up to the nearest power of two.

Comment: @AGNGazer where did you find that? At the end of the question it says `[10.08, 12.155, ...` or am I utterly confused?

Comment: @PaulPanzer no you are not, I think AGN got confused. And yes, I do need that behavior.

Comment: @Gabriel Ok, I think I fixed it. Could you please try it for size?

Comment: Your new code is correct, but now I've realized that the previous one was more efficient than mine. Could you roll back to it please (or add it to your answer)?

Comment: @Gabriel It is still there. Just pass `force_power_of_two=False` and it branches to the old code.

Comment: Thanks! I'm selecting this answer for conciseness.

Answer (score 1):

For ordered arrays:

```
def slpitArr(arr, step=3.):
    d = np.ediff1d(arr)
    n = (d / step).astype(dtype=np.int)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(n)
    indices = np.repeat(idx, n[idx]) + 1
    values = np.concatenate(
        [np.linspace(s1, s2, i+1, False)[1:] for s1, s2, i in zip(arr[:-1], arr[1:], n)])
    return np.insert(arr, indices, values)
```

Then

```
>>> aa = np.array([10.08, 14.23, 19.47, 21.855, 24.34, 25.02])
>>> print(slpitArr(aa))
[10.08  12.155 14.23  16.85  19.47  21.855 24.34  25.02 ]

>>> print(slpitArr(aa, 2.5))
[10.08       12.155      14.23       15.97666667 17.72333333 19.47
 21.855      24.34       25.02      ]
```

Comment: That can't be right. What are those >30. values doing there?

Comment: @Gabriel My example `aa` is different from yours. Given my `aa` what should be the answer?

Comment: @Gabriel Ah, my approach does not assume it is an ordered array. I forgot you have specified the array was _ordered_.

Comment: This will apparently fail if `step` is a float and not an integer.

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`.

Comment: @Gabriel Fixed now. Obviously, just like Paul, I am having trouble copying and pasting.

Comment: It runs now, but the results are different from my code. So, still no :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181713/discussion-between-agn-gazer-and-gabriel).

Comment: Try step=2.5 Still no.

Comment: @Gabriel I think it works as expected for 2.5. I do not understand wha do you expect for 2.5?

Comment: @Gabriel I see. I think your code inserts too many (more than needed) values. For example, between 14.23 and 19.47 my code inserts two values:       15.97666667 and 17.72333333 while your code inserts three values: 15.54,  16.85, and 18.16. Why are you inserting more than necessary values?

Comment: You are correct, although the results are not the same your code seems to do the splitting more efficiently than mine. Thank you! (Also, I've fixed two typos.)